# How to get the pluck results as a collection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

So I am working on a RESTApi with Laravel.

I am trying to get all the products that the buyer has bought. The thing is that buyer and products they are related through transactions table. Now the code below I am getting the results needed back since I am using Laravel eagerloading to get transactions with their products like so:

```
     /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index(Buyer $buyer)
{

    $products = $buyer->transactions()->with('product')->get()->pluck('products');



    return $this->showAll($products);
}
```

The thing here is that I have a trait that is being called on my base ApiController that trait has a method `showAll()` to return/display a `json` response of the request. The `showAll()` method expects a collection to be returned.  While I am sending a property of a collection instead.

**My question:**
How do I get back the products after eagerloading as collections instead of property ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `collect()`helper function to convert your `$products` array to collection.

Refer more on the doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#introduction

Comment: actually I made it work by changing the namespace on trait from Eloquent/Collection to Helper/Collection but I am researching on differences between those two namespaces. hmm that collect helper function basically converts an array to collection. ? Will try with that.